# how can i add event listener to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, dom

How can i add event listener for element that created with innerHTML? 
in my example code i want add event listener for X button

```
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-input-text">add</button>
 <script>
  var addInputText = document.querySelector('.add-input-text');
  var userForm = document.querySelector('.user-form');

   addInputText.addEventListener('click', function(){
   userForm.innerHTML += `<button class="form-section-remove- 
   1">X</button>`;
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event listener like how you normally would.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-input-text">add</button>
 <script>
  var addInputText = document.querySelector('.add-input-text');
  var userForm = document.querySelector('.user-form');

   addInputText.addEventListener('click', function(){
   userForm.innerHTML += `<button class="form-section-remove- 
   1">X</button>`;
   document.querySelector(".form-section-remove-1").addEventListener(/*whatever you're doing*/)
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a querySelector whose result can only be the button you made, or you could create the button using `document.createElement('button')`, add an event listener and use `appendChild` to add the button to the userForm.

```js
// Works if the is only one button in .user-form with .form-section-remove-1
document.querySelector('.user-form > button.form-section-remove-1').addEventlistener(...);
```

or alternatively

```js
const xButton = document.createElement('button');
xButton.innerText = 'X';
xButton.classlist.add('form-section-remove-1');
xButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   // Do whatever
}); 
userForm.appendChild(xButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You add it exactly the same way you add any other event listener. You just have to do it after the dynamically added element has been added to the DOM.

```js
var addInputText = document.querySelector('.add-input-text');
var userForm = document.querySelector('.user-form');
  
addInputText.addEventListener('click', function(){
  userForm.innerHTML += 
  "<button class='form-section-remove-1'>X</button>";
  
  // Now that the new element has been added to the DOM,
  // you can work with it as you would any other element.
  document.querySelector("button.form-section-remove-1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("You clicked me!");
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-input-text">add</button>
<div class="user-form"></div>
```

The problem that you'll run into though is that because you are using `.innerHTML` to add the new element to the DOM and because you are potentially adding more than one of them, we don't have a way for the second and subsequent buttons to be referenced easily.

Instead, if you create the new elements using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and [`.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), it becomes much simpler:

```js
var addInputText = document.querySelector('.add-input-text');
var userForm = document.querySelector('.user-form');
  
addInputText.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Create the element as a new DOM node
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  
  // Now, configure it through its properties and methods:
  btn.textContent = "X";
  btn.classList.add("form-section-remove-1");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("You clicked me!");
  });
  
  // Append it into the DOM
  userForm.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success add-input-text">add</button>
<div class="user-form"></div>
```